# Python not loading information correctly?

Tags: python

I don't understand. When I run the *SaveModule.open* function in this code, it's able to save *ShoppingCart.items_in_cart* in the correct variable correctly, but not *users*. Did I do something wrong in this code?

(I realize this might not be the most efficient code in the world, it's still a work in progress. Just trying to get everything working first.)

I tested this in the IDLE program, and everything worked the way it was supposed to, I just don't get what I did wrong here.

As for why I'm trying to do this, it's just a challenge I set for myself. Nothing more.

```
import os
import linecache
import ast
users = {}
logged_in = False
mspw = '00415564'

class ShoppingCart(object):
    #Creates shopping cart objects for users of our fine website.
    items_in_cart = {}
    def __init__(self, customer_name):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
    def __repr__(self):
        return(self.customer_name)
    def __str__(self):
        print('Hello ' + self.customer_name)
        print('You have ' + str(len(self.items_in_cart)) + ' items in your cart.')
        for item in self.items_in_cart:
            print('     ' + item, self.items_in_cart[item])
        return('Thank you for shopping at Job Simulator!')
    def add_item(self, product, price):
        #add a product to the cart
        if not product in self.items_in_cart:
            self.items_in_cart[product] = price
            print(product + ' added.')
        else:
            print(product + ' is already in the cart.')
    def change_price(self, product, price):
        if product in self.items_in_cart:
            self.items_in_cart[product] = price
            print('Price Changed')
        else:
            print('Impossible!')
    def change_item(self, product, newproduct):
        if product in self.items_in_cart:
            tempstor = self.items_in_cart[product]
            del self.items_in_cart[product]
            self.items_in_cart[newproduct] = tempstor
            print('Item changed')
        else:
            print('Impossible')
    def remove_item(self, product):
        #Remove product from the cart.
        if product in self.items_in_cart:
            del self.items_in_cart[product]
            print(product + ' removed.')
        else:
            print(product + ' is not in the cart.')


class UserModule(object):
    def add_user(usnm, pswd):
        if logged_in == False:
            if not usnm in users:
                users[usnm] = pswd
                s = True
            else:
                s = False
        else:
            s = False
        return s
    def remove_user(usnm, pswd):
        if logged_in == False:
            if usnm in users:
                if pswd == users[usnm]:
                    del users[usnm]
                    s = True
                else:
                    s = False
            else:
                s = False
        else:
            s = False
        return s
    def check_users(mst):
        if mst == mspw:
            for item in users:
                print('     ' + item, users[item])
        else:
            print('Need master password')

class SaveModule(object):
    def save(file):
        svflu = open(file + '.sbcu', 'w')
        svfli = open(file + '.sbci', 'w')
        svflu.truncate()
        svfli.truncate()
        svflu.write(str(users))
        svfli.write(str(ShoppingCart.items_in_cart))
        svflu.close()
        svfli.close()
    def open(file):
        if os.path.isfile(file + '.sbcu') and os.path.isfile(file + '.sbci'):
            svfl = open(file + '.sbcu', 'r')
            users = ast.literal_eval(linecache.getline(file + '.sbcu', 1))
            svfl.close()
            svfl = open(file + '.sbci', 'r')
            ShoppingCart.items_in_cart = ast.literal_eval(linecache.getline(file + '.sbci', 1))
            svfl.close()
        else:
            print('This file doesn\'t exits.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem; it was solved by nesting the *users* variable inside the *UserModule* module. I don't know why that fixed it; if anyone can answer that, then let me know.